# Regular expression matching in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to use the minimum possible code(number of character-wise) to check whether a two same length words differ by just one character. I've got one logic, where I use a for loop to step through every single character in the word and checking if the entire set has only one character different... But that seems to be a long piece of code...

Can someone suggest some regular expression that can be used to do it in a more compact fashion??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code-golf.  It might be on-topic at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concat the two words and use this pattern:

```
"bilboquetbilbaquet" =~ /^(.*)(.)(.*)\1(?!\2).\3$/   # exactly one character different

"bilboquetbilbaquet" =~ /^(.*)(.)(.*)\1.\3$/  # one character max
```

pattern details:

```
^         # anchor for the start of the string
(.*)      # capture group 1: zero or more characters
(.)       # capture group 2: one character
(.*)      # capture group 3: zero or more characters
\1        # backreference to group 1
(?!\2)    # negative lookahead: not followed by group 2 content
.         # one character
\3        # backreference to group 3
$         # anchor for the end of the string
```

example:

```
my $strA = "bilboquet";
my $strB = "bilbaquet";

my $result = ($strA.$strB) =~ /^(.*)(.)(.*)\1(?!\2).\3$/;

print $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the one character max expression... But, Can you please explain what you're doing?? I've basic idea of regex, but I'm not able to understand the expression...

Comment: This regex: /^(.*)(.)(.*)\1.\3$/ fits "bilboquetbilbaquet" like this:
/^(bilb)o(quet)(bilb)a(quet)$/